# Não consigo importar o valor do input numerico "Ano de Nascimento"

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, input

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Verificador de Idade</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------- -->

    <header>
        <h1>Verificador de Idade</h1>
    </header>

<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------- -->

    <section>
        <div> 
            <p> Ano de Nascimento:
                <input type="number" name="txtano" id="txtano" min="0">
            </p>
            <p> Sexo:
                <input type="radio" name="rsex" id="mas" checked>
                <label for="mas">Masculino</label>
                <input type="radio" name="rsex" id="fem">
                <label for="fem">Feminino</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="botao" onclick="verificar()" type="button" value="Verificar">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="res">
            Preencha os dados acima para ver o resultado!
        </div>
    </section>

<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------- -->

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; ﾒ</p>
    </footer>

<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------- -->

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

section {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.238);
}

footer {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
}

input#botao {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 2px;
}

input#botao:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.36);
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 1px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

input#txtano{
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50px;
}

div#res {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function verificar() {
    var res = document.getElementById('res');
    var fano = document.getElementById('txtano');
    var aano = new Date().getFullYear();
    if (fano.value.length == 0 || fano.value > aano) {
        alert('[ERRO] Verifique os dados e tente novamente');
    } else {
        alert('ok' + fano);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá, no --> [  alert('ok' + fano); ] adicione [.value]

```
<script>
    function verificar() {
    var res = document.getElementById('res');
    var fano = document.getElementById("txtano");
    var aano = new Date().getFullYear();

    if (fano.value.length == 0 || fano.value > aano) {
        alert('[ERRO] Verifique os dados e tente novamente');
    } else {
        alert('ok' + fano.value);
    }
}
</script>
```

[imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN0lW.png)